# What techniques can be used for faster time trial runs in Mario Kart 8?

Tags: mario-kart-8

While watching world records, I have noticed that many runs for Mario Kart 8 are simply faster than me, even if I am using the exact same kart. This is obvious right off the start as I start much slower even though I am using the rocket start. Are there secrets that allow these players to have a much higher acceleration and speed at the beginning and throughout the track?

Comment: They jump to preserve momentum from boosts. I'm not sure exactly how it works yet though.

Comment: Has that always been a thing? Maybe it's a side effect from adding gliders.

Comment: As for the start boost, are you getting the full boost? You can get a partial boost if you press A slightly late.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Fire Hopping** is a technique that can be used to make your speed gain from a boost last longer. As [discovered by](http://www.reddit.com/r/mariokart/comments/276814/top_ghosts_hopping/) a Reddit User, KaiserYoshi, it seems that any form of ground contact will begin to decrease the speed increase you gain from a boost, taking you back to your base speed. Therefore if you hop by pressing `ZR` you will go airborne, which the game doesn't count as touching the ground, and thus won't reduce your speed gain.

**Useful Links:**

- [Video explaining the technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zC519Ned_8) courtesy of IGN.
- [Kotaku's Coverage of the technique](http://kotaku.com/tag/fire-hopping)

Comment: Do we know if it's a "bug" / design-flaw yet or a real feature intended to be discovered by racers?