# How is drifting with a bike different than drifting with a kart?

Tags: mario-kart-8

I normally play using a kart, but most my friends play with a bike. I tried playing with a bike and I was completely unable to make any turns, it seems like the entire process of drifting (when to start, what the curve looks like, when to stop) is completely different than on a kart.

How do you adjust the drifting strategy when making turns with a bike?

Comment: Feels pretty normal to me...I'm not sure anything will help but practice really, it's the sort of thing you need the feel for more than a manual for.

Comment: I'd say drifting with a bike is more aggressive than drifting with a kart. You don't need to anticipate as much as on a kart, but you also need to be more careful on short curves if you want the drift boost. Unfortunately I'm currently unable to do research on my Wii U, so take my comment with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 6):

Some bikes have different drifting physics than other vehicles. This is known as "inside drifting" as opposed to the standard "outside drifting". The differences between the two are outlined [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170820/what-does-it-mean-for-a-bike-to-be-inside-drifting-versus-outside-drifting). You can tell which bikes are inside-drifting because they have a very slightly different icon next to their name (or you can just try it out, it's easy enough to tell).

Comment: yep, what Toomai said. Off the top of my head, sports bike, yoshi bike etc. are inside drifting which if you are used to the "standard" drifting of mario kart can be hard to get used to at first (although there are many who prefer this style, particularly as many consider inside-drifting bikes to have been the optimum vehicle for playing MKWii)