# What is interior and exterior drifting?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I've heard of 'inverse' or 'interior' drifting, and same with exterior... I think it was to do with statistics or something... What's the difference and how does it affect gameplay?

Comment: Related: [What does it mean for a bike to be inside-drifting versus outside-drifting?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/170820/46740)

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean modifying your drift path?

You can do this by steering more to the left (or right) while you are already drifting.
For example, if you're drifting left, you can get a sharper drift by steering even more to the left, or a wider drift by steering to the right; lesser to the left.
(Of course, reverse the directions if you're drifting to the right)

Just note that you can only do this while having your drift mode set to manual.

The example below shows the difference in paths when doing a wide/sharp drift as compared to a normal drift to the right.

[image: Difference in drift paths]

Comment: 1+ That picture was mesmerizing

Comment: This was helpful, but not what I was looking for. As in the two drifting settings, I have found out and apparently bicycles such as the Mach bike turn sharper than the others, so this is an 'inverse bike'. Thanks anyway, though.